# How to get speaking urls in TYPO3 9.5.5 with html but not for rootpage

Tags: routes, typo3, typo3-9.x

the building of speaking urls in TYPO3 9.5.5 is very nice. I tried out this:

```
routeEnhancers:
  PageTypeSuffix:
    type: PageType
    default: '.html'
    index: 'index'
    map:
     {}
```

It works fine, but for the rootpage there is example.org/index.html or example.org/en/index.html - I want to have example.org or example.org/en.html as it was before with realurl?
Is there any possibility to get rid of the index.html?

cu

Volker

Comment: With the default settings (if you omit all configurations u made) TYPO3 does not inlude your ".html"-suffix anymore for pages.

Either you messed up with your configuration or you have to provide more information about your site/setup s.o. and what you try to achieve

Comment: Thanks for response

I build  afresh version in docker and installed the introduction package and then I added a second language via "sites" 
and then the only edit was the config.yaml with
routeEnhancers:
  PageTypeSuffix:
    type: PageType
    default: '.html'
    index: 'index'
    map:
       {}
now I get links like this in menue http://mydomain/example.html - ok!
But for the root page I get http://mydomain/index.hml - I want to have only http://mydomain

Answer (score 0):

With the SEO (Core-Extension) I get the right canonical-tags, when I use "/" for the rootpage.
But it would nice to have the Urls for the frontpage without .html in the menu and rootline.

cu
Volker